# Do you agree with this!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So yeah, I stuck with this theory. I thought -4 Square = 16

[image]

Comment: What's new have you found?

Comment: Agree: $\;-16=-4^2\neq (-4)^2=16\;$ . This illustrates another use of parentheses in mathematics: to *enclose* some expression upon which some operation is going to apply. In this case, the operation is exponentiation (or whatever it is written).

Comment: By order of operations the above is correct.

Comment: [Somewhat related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210351/how-to-explain-to-a-14-year-old-that-sqrt-32-isnt-3)

Comment: Yes @MagicMan I would like to flag it as duplicate.

Comment: @SufyanSheikh It's not a duplicate--it's just somewhat related--something that may help OP reason through another problem with similar quandaries.

Comment: It's very much same however...

Comment: Thanks to everybody who have nice manners

Answer (score 4):

The point of the first line is that we evaluate exponents before other operations such as negation or subtraction. Therefore, we evaluate $-4^2$ as $-(4^2)$, not as $(-4)^2$. Therefore, under the usual order of operations,

$$-4^2=-(4^2)=-16$$

Remember, it is [PEMDAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics): Exponents come before subtraction.